# Calling templated member-pointer through templated class-object

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this not work ?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename C, typename ... Args>
void callMember( void (C::*method)( Args &&... ), C *this_, Args &&... args )
{
    this_->*method( forward<Args>( args ) ... );
}

struct S
{
    void f( string &&, string && );
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    callMember( (void (S::*)( string &&, string && ))&S::f,
        &s, string( "hello" ), string( "world" ) );
}
```

In the call of method inside f() the compiler complains: "term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments".

Comment: `(this_->*method)( forward<Args>( args ) ... );`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that due to **operator precedence** the expression `this_->*method( forward<Args>( args ) ... )` is treated as(equivalent to):

```
(this_)->*(method( forward<Args>( args ) ... )); //equivalent to this due to operator precedence
```

To **solve** this we need to override this behavior which we can do by parenthesizing the expression as shown below:

```
(this_->*method)( forward<Args>( args ) ... ); //note the extra parenthesis provided here to override the old behavior
```